# File does not exist error

Tags: php, joomla, joomla1.5

hi,

I am using joomla , i have enabled SEF, Site working fine but getting File does not exist error in access log. i am not modified anything in the .htaccess file, i just used below code.

Code:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/index.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (/|\.php|\.html|\.htm|\.feed|\.pdf|\.raw|/[^.]*)$  [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) index.php
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization},L]
```

Comment: which file? can you paste any errors regarding this from your error log please

Comment: sample: [Wed Feb 17 14:19:32 2013] [error] [client 88.113.248.170] File does not exist: /home/virtual/site4/fst/var/www/html/colombia-news, referer: http://OURWEBSITEDOMAIN.com/colombia-news/culture/8209-barranquilla-carnival-opens-before-800-thousand-spectators-photos.html

Comment: just had a look at your website and I don't see this error

Comment: mine is intranet, so i posted similar of someone details.